# How do I detect if Windows Explorer is displaying a given folder?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, mfc

My program creates a folder in the executable's directory and saves some output files. When the application finishes, I have it automatically open the folder in an explorer window using `ShellExecute(NULL, _T("Open"), _T("Explorer"), _T(m_strOutputPath), NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);`

Now, if I keep re-running the program, it will just keep opening the same folder even if it is already opened. For the absent-minded user (with me being one of them), this results in multiple windows of the same folder.

Is there a way to detect if the folder is already opened in an explorer window and not make it open a new window if it is already opened?

I'm developing in MSVS 2008 SP1 on Windows Vista, but the program will run on XP, Vista, and 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It will open a folder window and select the files given. If the window is already open, it'll bring it to the front.

Internally, it uses the [IShellWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836570%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) interface, specifically the FindWindowSW method.

Comment: What are the steps on how to use this to find a window's existence?

Comment: You probably need to call it from a single-threaded COM apartment. That is: from a thread that's called OleInitialize, CoInitialize, or AfxOleInit.

Comment: Or, rather than using ShellExecute and passing the "Open" verb, you could run explorer.exe directly. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510 for the command-line arguments.

Comment: Using the COM stuff is too advanced for me and running explorer still opens in separate windows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ShellExecute(NULL, _T("Open"), _T(m_strOutputPath), NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
```