# Getting the current IShellView user is interacting with

Tags: windows, winapi

I am writing a Shell Extension with a Context Menu handler. When right clicking a file, and selecting the context menu item, another file in the same folder is created.

I want the new file to be automatically selected in Windows File Explorer after the operation, as if the user had pasted the file. For what I understand I need to use [IShellView::SelectItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellview-selectitem). But how do I get the current [IShellView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellview) object of the Shell (File Explorer) the user is interacting with?

Comment: I dont understand your question.
If you click some item in shell namespace you have itemidlist of this item.
So you have also parent itemidlist for this item, from which construct another pidl for the new file, which pass to the IShellView::selectItem

Comment: you can use [`SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj_core/nf-shlobj_core-shopenfolderandselectitems) for this. *pidlFolder* you got from `IShellExtInit::Initialize` and for new file you can say `LPCITEMIDLIST apidl = ILCreateFromPath(L"*\\<new file name>");`  and finally `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(pidlFolder, 1, &apidl, 0);`

Comment: Thank you, that does make sense. If you don’t mind me asking, how would I get the IShellView folder view object to call the selectItem member function on?

Comment: I will try this later. :) Is the folder opened in a new window? The new file is created in the same folder so I would like it to use the same window and not open a new one.

Comment: in my test in the same window

Comment: the `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` internal call [`IShellWindows::FindWindowSW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/exdisp/nf-exdisp-ishellwindows-findwindowsw) with passed *pidlFolder* and if found - use this window for select item. but window for *pidlFolder* must exist. you got it pidl from `IShellExtInit::Initialize`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4889117/6401656

Comment: Query your site for `SID_SFolderView` and `IShellView`, and if successful, call `IShellView::SelectItem`. Note that the query may fail if your context menu is not being shown in the context of a folder.

Comment: @RbMm Clever idea but won't work if the user is working on the desktop.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - probably. i not check this from context menu extension. simply as idea

Comment: @RbMm Ok I managed to try `SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems` and it would have been super simple to use, but looks like there are more special cases in Explorer. For example "username" and "This PC>C:>Users>username" are different so it [opens a new window](https://i.imgur.com/BlzhUwL.png) when called from the former. So close. :)

Comment: @Mr.RanDum but really  Raymond Chen give you perfect solution here. you need implement `IObjectWithSite` on your object. shell call `SetSite` on your object, you query `IServiceProvider` from given interface and on it call `QueryService(__uuidof(IFolderView), IID_PPV_ARGS(&psv))`on `IShellView* psv;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need implement [`IObjectWithSite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ocidl/nn-ocidl-iobjectwithsite) interface o your context menu object:

```
class CMenuExtension : IShellExtInit, IContextMenu, IObjectWithSite {.. };
```

as result `SetSite` will be called after `CMenuExtension::Initialize` and before `CMenuExtension::QueryContextMenu`. here you can use passed `pUnkSite` for get [`IFolderView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifolderview) and/or [`IShellView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellview) interface. something like this

```
virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetSite( 
    /* [in] */ __RPC__in_opt IUnknown *pUnkSite)
{
    if (_pUnkSite)
    {
        _pUnkSite->Release();

        if (_pfv)
        {
            _pfv->Release();
            _pfv = 0;
        }
    }

    _pUnkSite = pUnkSite;

    if (pUnkSite)
    {
        pUnkSite->AddRef();

        IServiceProvider* psp;

        if (0 <= pUnkSite->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&psp)))
        {
            IFolderView* pfv;

            if (0 <= psp->QueryService(__uuidof(IFolderView), IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfv)))
            {
                _pfv = pfv;

                IShellFolder* psf;

                if (0 <= pfv->GetFolder(IID_PPV_ARGS(&psf)))
                {
                    STRRET sr;
                    if (0 <= psf->GetDisplayNameOf(0, SHGDN_FORPARSING , &sr))
                    {
                       ...
                    }
                    psf->Release();
                }
            }

            psp->Release();
        }
    }

    return S_OK;
}
```

so you need first ask site interface for `IServiceProvider` interface and then call

```
QueryService(__uuidof(IFolderView), IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfv)
```

for `__uuidof(IFolderView)` for  `IFolderView` and/or `IShellView` interface.

with say `IFolderView` tou can get `IShellFolder` interface also. remember this interfaces in object and then use from `InvokeCommand`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much RbMm and Raymond Chen. :-)